# Inline JS is not called in html form

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, reference, inline

I have a html file with some inline JS, and I want to call a function when a user submits a form.

My code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Color Blast</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    function hexToHSL(hex) {
      var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
      r = parseInt(result[1], 16);
      g = parseInt(result[2], 16);
      b = parseInt(result[3], 16);
      r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
      var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
      var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;
      if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
      }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
          case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
          case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
          case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
      }
      var HSL = new Object();
      HSL['h']=h;
      HSL['s']=s;
      HSL['l']=l;
      return HSL;
    }
    function myFunction() {
      var color_code = document.getElementByClassName("color_code").value;
      document.getElementsByClassName("light").style.backgroundColor = hexToHsl(color_code);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="color_code" name="color_code" placeholder="Write a color code">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!" onclick="return myFunction();">
</form>
<div style="border-radius: 300px; width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div class="light" style="border-radius: 300px; width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div class="dark" style="border-radius: 300px; width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that when I call `myFunction()`, in the form it throws a **ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined**

So my question is. Why is my function not found on `onckick`?

Comment: Your code is ignored because you have given a *src* attribute.

Comment: Ok, so what can I do if I also want to write jQuery

Comment: I think you should start by getting to know the basics. Learn how to include javascript from external sources and how to add your own scripts.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work now.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate in 2 scripts, one with `src`, the other with code. Having both inside one script is invalid in HTML5.

You also have other errors, for a start `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByClassName` (plural)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Color Blast</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function hexToHSL(hex) {
      var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
      r = parseInt(result[1], 16);
      g = parseInt(result[2], 16);
      b = parseInt(result[3], 16);
      r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
      var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
      var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;
      if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
      }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
          case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
          case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
          case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
      }
      var HSL = new Object();
      HSL['h']=h;
      HSL['s']=s;
      HSL['l']=l;
      return HSL;
    }
    function myFunction() {
      var color_code = document.getElementByClassName("color_code").value;
      document.getElementsByClassName("light").style.backgroundColor = hexToHsl(color_code);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="color_code" name="color_code" placeholder="Write a color code">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!" onclick="return myFunction();">
</form>
<div style="border-radius: 300px; width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div class="light" style="border-radius: 300px; width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
<div class="dark" style="border-radius: 300px; width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```